# Работа с базами данных Android

Tags: android, база-данных

Есть внешняя база данных PostgreSQL, телефон с ней подключается, все отлично. Вопрос в чем, нужно данные из базы держать в памяти телефона, чтобы каждый раз не грузить эти данные с базы, а только проверять версии. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это работает в коммерческих приложениях? У них тоже есть внутренняя бд SQLite данные которой сверяются с внешней базой или как-то по другому это работает? Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я могу предложить только свое виденье решения данной проблемы. У вас есть внешняя бд и с ней все хорошо работает и теперь если я все правильно понял вам нужно как-то сделать локальную бд на телефоне чтобы не грузить постоянно все. Для этого я бы вам посоветовал при первом запуске приложения создавать такую же бд, например при помощи Room (вот есть [ссылка](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/529-urok-5-room-osnovy.html) например). То есть у вас все таблицы и данные в ячейках должны быть выгружены в вашу новую бд на телефоне.

Теперь у вас есть бд на телефоне, но вопрос в том как обновлять данные. Это довольно интересный вопрос, и его можно решить двумя способами (может и больше есть способов, но мне приходит на ум только два): первый - вы при каждом подключении к бд просматриваете каждую таблицу и ищите несоответствие вашей лок. бд и внешней и дальше уже перезаписываете данные или добавляете, либо есть второй вариант ( я не знаю как это реализовать, но думаю что это реально) - вы запрашиваете дату последнего изменения внешней бд, и сравниваете с датой последнего изменения бд на вашем телефоне, и если даты не соответствуют, то вы проводите апдейт, если же данные одинаковые то не нужно будет искать изменения в таблицах. В моем ответе к сожалению нету готового решения, так как я с таким вопросом столкнулся здесь впервые и поэтому могу попытаться вам помочь только с логической стороны вопроса, извините :) Если будут дополнительные вопросы, касательно моего ответа я постараюсь вам помочь используя все доступные ресурсы. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ) Т.е. как я понял с помощью библиотеки Room работаем с SQLite на телефоне, при этом если у нас есть новая версия базы PostgeSQL, то с нее данные переписываем на SQLite?

Comment: я указал room как решение с которым я работал, вот например есть статья - https://habr.com/post/325434/, там все красиво расписано.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: Спасибо, в случае чего могу с вами консультироваться?

Comment: Конечно, задавайте вопросы или здесь в комментариях отпишитесь мне:)